# How to set FirefoxDriver as the driver for Geb

Tags: geb

This seems to work:

```
@Grapes([ 
    @Grab("org.codehaus.geb:geb-core:0.7.2"),
    @Grab("org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-htmlunit-driver:2.25.0"),
    @Grab("org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-support:2.25.0"),
    @Grab("org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-firefox-driver:2.25.0")
])

import geb.Browser
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver

Browser.drive() {

    go "http://www.google.com"
}
```

But how do I use `FirefoxDriver` instead of `HtmlUnitDriver`? This just starts Firefox but all the `drive` instructions are executed in `HtmlUnitDriver`...

```
@Grapes([ 
    @Grab("org.codehaus.geb:geb-core:0.7.2"),
    @Grab("org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-htmlunit-driver:2.25.0"),
    @Grab("org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-support:2.25.0"),
    @Grab("org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-firefox-driver:2.25.0")
])

import geb.Browser
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver

def browser = new Browser(driver: new FirefoxDriver())

browser.drive {

    go "http://www.google.com"

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a configuration script as outlined here: http://www.gebish.org/manual/0.7.0/configuration.html

Answer (score 1):

We have done following configuration in the GebConfig.groovy to register FireFoxDriver with Geb.

```
driver = {
    def firefoxDriver = new FirefoxDriver()
    SharedResources.instance.browser = firefoxDriver
    firefoxDriver.manage().window().maximize()
    firefoxDriver
}
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Browser.drive(new FirefoxDriver()) {

    // firefox 

}
```